# What is regular about regular languages?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, regular-languages

I am new to automata theory. I am well aware of the definition of regular language in automata, that is "a language is called a regular language if some finite automaton recognizes/accepts it" [MS]. However, I'm confused why such language (set of strings) is called regular.

1. what is regular about regular language?
2. Is there any relation between regular set in automata theory and regular set in mathematics?

Comment: @DavidRicherby http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8739/why-are-regular-languages-called-regular

Comment: Kleene already uses the term 'regular' in his 1951 memo (and 1956 article) that appears to introduce the notion of a regular language: [Representation of events in nerve nets and finite automata](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2008/RM704.pdf).